# Need help finding the datasheet of this IC

Tags: datasheet, reverse-engineering

I'm trying to find out what this IC is and appreciate any help! It is located inside an EV charging cable and its main task from plugs datasheet is:

"STATIC RESISTANCE
 (FROM PROX. DETECTION TO GROUND) 150ohm
 RESISTANCE WILL INCREASE TO 480ohm WHEN
 LATCH IS DEPRESSED" (No more info on datasheet about this mini circuit)

Here is the reverse-engineered schematics of the small pcb in the charging plug:

[image: Here is the reverse-engineered schematics of the small pcb in the charging plug]

Scope picture of unknown IC
[image: Scope picture of unknown IC]

I guessed it might have been ADM803/ADM809/ADM810 which is same package but unfortunately pinouts doesnt match.

Comment: That's a SOT package. You can basically buy any low- to medium-power transistor in this universe in that shape. Good luck.

Answer (score 3):

Looks like the ADM810 Reset 1shot chip

[image: ADM810 datasheet]

Comment: At the end of their question, the OP said that they don't think it's that part, because the pinout doesn't match. Are you saying they're wrong?

Comment: They are correct. C4 goes across pin 3 (centre IN) and 1  ( left GND)